# Hotot twitter client: search fails

Tags: hotot

In the desktop version of Hotot 0.9.8.14-0, search views fail with HTTP 406, 'reason: not acceptable' (ubuntu 13.04).

The API URL for searches is https://twitter.com/phoenix_search.phoenix

Is there a way to have functional search views, other than moving to another program ?

Answer (score 1):

This error has been fixed as of Nov 28th, but I dont think it is part of a release yet.

https://github.com/lyricat/Hotot/pull/578